# How to get element's className, Id, and nth:child(n) in order to be a good stable querySelector?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, element, selector, puppeteer

I am getting element by X, Y coordinates. I would like my final string result to look like Inspect -> copySelector:

> body > div.layout.slidein-page-container > main > div.ng-scope > section.wrapper.wrapper--canvas > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2)

So it will be good queryString to evaluate JSHandle from it.

Here is my code:

```
let chosenElement = await page.evaluate((payload) => {
        return document.elementsFromPoint(payload.data.x, payload.data.y)
            .map((o) => {
                if (o.id) {
                    return o.id;
                } else if (o.className) {
                    if (o.className.includes(' ')) {
                        return o.tagName.toLowerCase() + '.' + o.className.split(' ').join('.');
                    } else {
                        return o.tagName.toLowerCase() + '.' + o.className;
                    }
                } else {
                    return o.tagName.toLowerCase();
                }
            }).reverse().join(' > ');
    }, payload);
```

So currently I am only checking for className and Id, but I want to make this more precise.

**The first ting I want help is how do I check if element is nth-child(2) for example?**

Can you help me with a better solution please

Comment: If you can get an element from x,y, you can use that directly as jshandle, what send the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the element's parent children from HTMLCollection to an array with:

```
Array.from(o.parentElement.children)
```

find the index of your element:

```
const oIndex = Array.from(o.parentElement.children).indexOf(o);
```

return the selector:

```
return `${o.tagName}:nth-child(${oIndex + 1})`;
```

you need to add 1 because nth-child starts at 1, where indexes in array starts at 0;

BTW:

- you forgot to add a `#` before the id when building the selector.
- you don't need to lowercase the tagname in your selector
- if the object has a className you can simply return `${o.tagName}.${Array.from(o.classList).join('.')}`

Comment: Awesome answer, but puppeteer is throwing an exception: Cannot read property 'children' of null.....

Comment: Check this issue, someone already had this problem: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2800

Comment: I got it working (no error) with o.parentNode.children and now I need to find good index since this count all the elements within the parent node (img, div, etc..) and for example I only need div:nth-child(2)

Comment: if you don't use `:nth-of-type` you can keep the index from parent.children (you still need to add 1)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help some other guys

```
  let chosenElement = await page.evaluate((payload) => {
        return document.elementsFromPoint(payload.data.x, payload.data.y)
            .map((o) => {
                let sibArr = Array.from(o.parentNode.children).filter(i => i.tagName === o.tagName);
                if (sibArr.indexOf(o) > 0) {
                    let oIndex = sibArr.indexOf(o);
                    return `${o.tagName.toLowerCase()}:nth-child(${oIndex + 1})`;
                } else if (o.id) {
                    return '#' + o.id;
                } else if (o.className) {
                    return `${o.tagName.toLowerCase()}.${Array.from(o.classList).join('.')}`
                } else {
                    return o.tagName.toLowerCase();
                }
            }).reverse().filter(e => !e.includes('html')).join(' > ');
    }, payload);
```

This meets the desired result:

```
body > div:nth-child(3) > header.layout__header.slidein-page > div.container > nav.nav-bar > ul.nav-bar__nav > li:nth-child(3) > a
```